# JWPLAYER custom error message

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I embedded JWPlayer on my page with custom error message that display different image when stream is not online but error image is  not loading.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        file: 'http://blog.com/stream.m3u8',
        image: 'http://blog.com/streamimage.png',
        title: 'STREAMING TITLE',
        width: '100%',
        height: "100%",
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        skin: 'glow',
        mute: 'true',
        ga: '{}'
    });
    jwplayer().onError(function(){
        jwplayer().load({image:"http://blog.com/streamimage-error.png"});
        jwplayer().play();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looking at the API docs, it seems you need to load a video file with the image value. `file:"http://blog.com/error.mp4"` for example.

Comment: according to this doc. http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message you can include image

Comment: Yeah, but you also need to include a link using the file attribute, if that is mandatory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1442607-example-a-custom-error-message)

You need to add file attribute as mentioned in the document `jwplayer().load({file:"http://jwplayer.com/errorfile.mp4",image:"http://jwplayer.com/errorfile.jpg"});`

you need to create a `error video` for this and change your code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        file: 'http://blog.com/stream.m3u8',
        image: 'http://blog.com/streamimage.png',
        title: 'STREAMING TITLE',
        width: '100%',
        height: "100%",
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        skin: 'glow',
        mute: 'true',
        ga: '{}'
    });
    jwplayer().onError(function(){
        jwplayer().load({file:"http://jwplayer.com/errorfile.mp4", image:"http://blog.com/streamimage-error.png"});
       // jwplayer().play();// i dont think you need to play video if it throws error
    });
</script>
```

I would recommend creating error video and error image and use it when error occurs.

Below code will be much helpful for constant stream monitoring.

```
jwplayer().onBuffer(function(){
theTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
jwplayer().load({file:"http://jwplayer.com/errorfile.mp4",image:"http://jwplayer.com/errorfile.jpg"});
jwplayer().play();
},5000);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: this was it. creating a error video is required for this feature to work!

Comment: your last script works after 5 seconds on play event but it doesn't work on onError event.